aiohttp behaviour when not reading body
In my current development, I am sending a request to 50-100 different servers at the same time with aiohttp, and I am in no need to read the body (only need status_code and headers). I also cannot use HEAD request for the purpose of my application.
My goals are:

Be able to utilize keep-alive's/Connection pooling with the 50-100 servers I mentioned.
Not loading the body into RAM, but discarding it.

I know that I need to read the body to be able to reuse the same socket for a new request (I know how TCP/HTTP works).
I searched the web for keywords like "aiohttp ignore body", "what resp.release() does", and delved into the source code however got lost in detail. I also served a local server (nginx) to check what aiohttp is doing. Although it looked like it was pooling the connections, at some point it did try to close connection for every request and create a new one. Which got me confused.
My questions are:

When I do async with session.request(url) as resp: and later don't call stuff that reads body like resp.text() how does aiohttp(context managers) handle this? Does it indeed read the body then discard? Are there exceptions?

Does body size come in to the equation at any point for this matter? Like the response body being 1KB or 1GB affect the keep-alive I am trying to achieve, other that download time itself.

Is there a documented way in aiohttp which I can indeed discard the socket along with the body?




When I do async with session.request(url) as resp: and later don't call stuff that reads body like resp.text() how does aiohttp(context managers) handle this? Does it indeed read the body then discard? Are there exceptions?

No, it prereads a chunk of data when entering the context (in order to parse the headers). If the full message hasn't been read, then it will close the connection (if it tried to read the body, then exiting the context manager could potentially block forever).
As you've already concluded, you will need to read the body yourself. To avoid memory issues, you'll need to use the streaming API. Just don't do anything with the result, so something like:
async for chunk in resp.content.iter_any():
    pass


Thanks for your answer. In my tests, contrary to your answer, I am apparently able to recycle connections. This could be from the fact that I used body sizes smaller than the initial read buffer (idk the size), so the whole body is inevitably consumed. But that's just a guess.

Yes, if they are small payloads (hence the if in my answer), then you're probably fine. I can't remember how much is preread, but it's probably around 4KiB.

I had assumed that your concern about reading the body into RAM meant that the payloads were large. If your payloads are small enough to fit in that preread, then they are being read into RAM regardless. So, that's not something you can avoid.

Ah yes, in production they may indeed be large. However during local tests, I used a smaller one (21kb actıally, but apparently buffer is 64kb). I will try a bigger response body when I have time.
